# NSInvalidArgumentException error. Not running under UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, universal

Whilst I understand why im receiving an error

'', reason: '-[UIPopoverController initWithContentViewController:] called when not running under UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad.'

Rectifying  it is becoming a bit tricky.  My pop over is only required on the ipad and not on the iphone version. I omitted any code for the iphones `if statement` and still got a crash.  .  Presuming that I must call a view on iphone as well as its a universal app,   I simply called the nib in the `if iphone statement`, and that didn't work either.

```
 - (IBAction)popZs:(id)sender {  




if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {

    if ([popoverController isPopoverVisible]) {
        [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    } else {

        [self->popoverController setPopoverContentSize: CGSizeMake(601, 571)];

        [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:((UIButton *)sender).bounds
                                           inView:sender
                         permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
                                         animated:YES];

    }



}
else {

    /////using iPhone/////not sure how to handle this spart
     zsTablePop *pop = [[zsTablePop alloc] init];
    pop.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [pop presentModalViewController:pop animated:YES];



}
```

Keep getting same erorr even though im using `if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {`

creation of pop over

```
.m


#import "ICCircuitDetails.h"
#import "zsTablePop.h"  ///////////////pop over xib/////

 @interface ICCircuitDetails ()



{
zsTablePop *controller;
UIPopoverController *popoverController;
}


 ///////more code/////////////


 - (id)initWithCircuit:(Circuit *)circuit
{


 self = [super initWithCertificate:circuit.distributionBoard.certificate];
if (self) {
    self.circuit = circuit;
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ICCircuitDetails" owner:self options:nil];
    self.view.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.contentView.frame.size.width,    self.contentView.frame.size.height);

 ///////////other code here/////////////////

if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) 

    controller = [[zsTablePop alloc] initWithNibName:@"zsTablePop" bundle:nil];
    popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:controller];
```

Comment: What do you see if you attempt to log the current device idiom?

Comment: It should be [self presentModalViewController:pop animated:YES];

Comment: @Moxy, i though that but I get a no `@ interface error` something else is declaring `present modal view animated`

Comment: In what class are you implementing -popZs: ?

Comment: What is the class `zsTablePop` a subclass of?

Answer (score 1):

Your error message says you try to instantiate a popover. The code only is about presenting it. You need to handle the instantiation as well.

Comment: Could you expand on that please? The pop over works fine on iPad, the error occurs when its running on iphone, Im not sure what it wants. I know i can present a popover on iphone so thought loading the nib would do but its still says `not running under UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad`

Comment: Where is that popover created? It seems it gets created on the iPhone as well - hence the error.

Comment: Oh got you. I have edited my question code showing creation of pop over, what do you think?

Comment: I can't comment on code showing only the half method. That method is called somewhere - maybe here, maybe somewhere else. Also check your nibs - if they contain a UIPovoverController, that might be a problem as well.

Comment: No nibs contain pop over controller its a UIVIew, the only other code I have for the method is in .h   `- (IBAction)popZs:(id)sender;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *show;` thats all the code now in the whole project for the pop pover

Comment: You might show your  - (id)initWithCircuit:(Circuit *)circuit method completely. You can also set a symbolic breakpoint to see where the init method on the UIPopoverController is called.

Comment: Sorry have done that in my original code now.  Thanks for your help so far